# displaying special characters with python utf-8 encoding

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

I have several XML files with utf-8 encoding. These files are in differenct languages. I need to parse these files(i am using the elementTree method), then get a specific text out of each file and then split that text. The problem arise when i try to parse in languages that have special characters inside(which is pretty match every language except english). I need the excact text shown in the xml files and not the encoding version of python in order for the split seperation to work and to get the recquired data out of the long texts that i am parsing.
I have read how encoding utf-8 works in python and specifically i reat this from official python documentation.

```
If the code point is < 128, it’s represented by the corresponding byte value.
If the code point is >= 128, it’s turned into a sequence of two, three, or four bytes, where each byte of the sequence is between 128 and 255.
```

I also read that from python 3 and later that the special characters can be displayed but I am using python 2.7 and the software tool I am running my program cannot support python 3.

The code is the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import sys
import io
import string
import codecs

print("using texttool_navi.py" + sXmlFile)

#intializing Variables
sAddress = ''
sAcronym = ''
sPlace = ''
sData = ''

# parse texttool file
Parser =et
tree = et.parse(sXmlFile)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    if child.attrib["ID"] == sID:
        schild = et.tostring(child,encoding = 'utf-8')
        print('line ' + schild)
        sData = child.text
        sData = string.split(sData, '"')
        print(sData)
        sAddress = sData[1]
        sAcronym = sData[3]
        sPlace = sData[5]
        if sID == 'a specific ID':
            sAddress = string.replace(sAddress, '\\n', ' ')
            sAcronym = string.replace(sAcronym, '\\n', ' ')
            sPlace  = string.replace(sPlace, '\\n', ' ')
```

the printing is there at the moment only for my convinience, it is not needed for the work i want to do.
to give you a more specific example one part of the text that is in the xml file is this:
Ettinger Straße

And what i am getting after converting the schild to string is this:
Ettinger StraÃŸeâ€œ

Is there a way to get the special characters to be dispalyed out of parsing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ElementTree processes Unicode and so should you.  `et.tostring` returns a byte string.  Printing that to a terminal that doesn't support UTF-8 will give you that garbage string.  Just the Unicode string via `print child.text`.  You still need to have a terminal that supports the Unicode characters in its current encoding.

I'm on Windows and the console by default supports `cp437` which includes most Western European language characters.  Note that printing the element text directly works:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
>>> test = et.Element('test')
>>> test.text = u'Héllo'
>>> print(et.tostring(test,encoding='utf8'))
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<test>H├⌐llo</test>
>>> print test.text
Héllo
```

Python will encode the Unicode string to the terminal encoding (which isn't UTF8).  If you print characters not supported by the terminal (say Chinese) you'll get a `UnicodeEncodeError`.  The solution to that if you run into it is to use a Python IDE that supports UTF-8, or write to files and view them in an editor that supports UTF-8.

Of course, current versions of Python (specifically 3.6+) support Unicode *much* better.  They ignore the Windows terminal encoding and call the Win32 APIs supporting Unicode directly.  They'll even handle Chinese to the terminal, although that requires font support to view properly.